# Solving a minimization problem without flattening inputs?

Tags: optimization, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulation, differential-equations

I am reading this paper on improving time steps for solving simulation problems:
[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~jteran/papers/GSSJT15.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ejteran/papers/GSSJT15.pdf)

The authors developed this energy  function:

$$E(x) = \frac{1}{2\Delta t ^ 2}(x-\hat x)^TM(x - \hat x) +  \phi$$

In this particular formulation, $x$ is the global, flattened, vector of particle positions, $M$ a lumped mass amtrix, $\hat x$ the global flattened vector of positions in the current time step and $\phi$ the flattened forces acting on all points.

The author's then solve for the minimizer by doing a hessian weighted gradient descent on this energy function.

This works, but has 2 things I don't like.

1. You have to flatten your vectors from each particle into a large global state vector,
2. and this does not parallelize too well.

Is it possible to retain the main contribution of the paper (large time steps)  but solve localized problems for each input particle instead of a global equation?

It really doesn't seem to me like you need global state for this as particles which are physically far away from each other should not impact the solution.

Comment: You can have a look at domain decomposition methods.

Comment: Is $M$ a full dense matrix?  Banded?  General Sparse?

Comment: Diagonal lumbed mass matrix